# Sql Override Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables  `user_profile`, `module`,`Role` `privilege_mapping`
With  privilege_mapping table entries as [ID,Module,privilege,userId,RoleID]

```
1 | Settings | true   | NULL  | 1  
2 | Settings | false  |   1   | 1  
3 | About    | true   | NULL  | 1  
4 | DashBoard| true   | NULL  | 1
```

I have a requirement that some user's some permissions has to be overriden(on/off) as against their role privileges.

for eq: User 1 is having a role id 1. As per role 1 settings is denied. But I have another overridden entry for user that it is enabled.

Preference should be given for user privileges.
So privileges for user 1 it should be

```
2 | Settings  | false |  1   | 1  
3 | About     | true  | NULL | 1  
4 | DashBoard | true  | NULL | 1
```

Am beginner in sql queries . How can I achieve the result
Any help will be appreciated

This is what i have done so far. But now it contains both rows

```
;WITH prvCTE AS
(
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    (
        SELECT module_id, url, privilege, module_name
        FROM [dbo].[UserProfile] U
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[privilege_mapping] P ON p.user_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[module] M ON p.module_id = M.id
        WHERE U.id = @userID


            EXCEPT

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        SELECT module_id, url, privilege, module_name
        FROM [dbo].[UserProfile] U
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[role] R ON U.RoleID = R.RoleID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[privilege_mapping] P ON p.role_id = R.RoleID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[module] M ON p.module_id = M.id
        WHERE U.id = @userID
    )
    UNION

    SELECT module_id, url, privilege, module_name
    FROM [dbo].[UserProfile] U
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[role] R ON U.RoleID = R.RoleID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[privilege_mapping] P ON p.role_id = R.RoleID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[module] M ON p.module_id = M.id
    WHERE U.id = @userID
)
SELECT *
FROM prvCTE
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff question restructured. Sorry for my bad English and sentence construction

Comment: Do you mean that if some (module, roleid) records are duplicated, then you prefer records with specific userid, where privilege=false? In CTE, order your records by preference (descending), generate rownums partitioned over module + roleid and select only records with rownum = 1.

Answer (score 3):

OK.  I think you need to consider 3 different circumstances:

1. User Exists, but user has NO UserPrivilege OR RolePrivilege
2. User Exists, and user has BOTH UserPrivilege AND RolePrivilege
3. User Exists, and has EITHER ONE

To account for all 3 in a single query, you need a couple of sub-queries and a couple of outer joins.

**SubQuery1:  UserPrivileges**

To get all your user privileges, we pull:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[privilege_mapping] WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
```

**SubQuery2:  RolePrivileges**

To get all of your ROLE privileges, we use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[privilege_mapping] WHERE user_id IS NULL
```

**Pulling it all together:  COALESCE()**

Finally, to use one OR the other (depending on which one exists), we use the COALESCE() statement.  This way (I think) we can do the entire select in a single statement:

```
SELECT module_id, url, privilege=COALESCE(UP.privilege,RP.privilege), module_name
   FROM [dbo].[UserProfile] U
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[privilege_mapping] WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL) UP ON UP.user_id = U.id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[privilege_mapping] WHERE user_id IS NULL) RP ON RP.role_id = U.role_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[module] M ON COALESCE(UP.module_id,RP.module_id)=M.id
   WHERE U.id = @userID AND M.id IS NOT NULL
```

**RoleId?**

I'm missing this from your schema.  Not sure how I can tell that a user plays a given "role"  I assume there is a role_id in the user table, but couldn't tell from the question.  So - I added that as the field on which we are joining.

**MODULE?**

OK.  I don't have the full schema, so I'm not sure if that last left-outer join to module is OK or not.  I have a feeling we need another where clause that gets rid of NULL module_id's (eg `WHERE module_id IS NOT NULL`).

NOTE that where clauses on a field that we pull from a LEFT OUTER JOIN are tricky (because it could turn the join into an INNER JOIN if you code it incorrectly).

Try this.  See how close we are, and then we can tweak.

Comment: For the first time am posting a question in sql. Don't know how much detailed framing is needed. Will definitely try this solution